# How to convert cv::Mat to void*

Tags: c++, opencv

I am making a DLL in C++ to use it in LabView, I get an RGB image and I convert it to grayscale. My code is the following:

```
DLLIMPORT void function (void* ImageSrc, void* ImageF)
{
    cv::Mat greyMat, colorMat;
    colorMat = cv::Mat(488, 648, CV_8U, (uchar*)ImageSrc);
    greyMat = (colorMat, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);


}
```

ImageF would be the gray image and I do not know how to copy grayMat in ImageF.

Comment: That all depends on what `ImageF` is. `void*` means an pointer to **anything**. This question cannot be answered unless you explain what sort of thing `ImageF` is actually pointing to. I mean I guess you want the image data copyed in the format you already have.

Comment: ImageF is pointing to an ImageIMAQ image which is only used in LabView

Comment: All I can suggest is that you consult the documentation for the APIs you are using. LabView in particular is unfamiliar to me.

Answer (score 1):

According to the following [post](https://stackoverrun.com/fr/q/9867789) it supposed to be very simple:

```
DLLIMPORT void function(void* ImageSrc, void* ImageF)
{
    cv::Mat colorMat = cv::Mat(488, 648, CV_8UC3, ImageSrc);
    cv::Mat greyMat = cv::Mat(488, 648, CV_8UC1, ImageF);
    cv::cvtColor(colorMat, greyMat, cv::COLOR_RGB2GRAY); //You may also try cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY
}
```

- The `ImageSrc` is RGB, so it is has 3 color channels, and the type should be `CV_8UC3` and not `CV_8U`.
- Create the gray `cv::Mat` with `ImageF` as `data` argument (and type `CV_8UC1`).
  There are multiple options for creating `cv:Mat` objects (constructor overloading).
  The above option sets `ImageF` to point the data of the image.
- Execute `cv::cvtColor` with `cv::COLOR_RGB2GRAY` conversion type, for converting from RGB to gray.

Note:
The resolution of the output image (684x488) and the type (gray type with one byte per pixel) must be defined in `LabView` **before** executing the function.
The size and type information are not passed from `function` to `LabView`.
Only the "raw" image data is passed to `LabView`.

Please let me know if it works, because I have no way to test it.